# How to delete mockable-android-23.jar automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I just upgraded to Android Studio 2.0.
I usually backup my project weekly and do clean project before backing up, after backup I noticed that my backup go up around 12mb in size.

I traced the big size, it comes from 'generated' folder in 'build' folder.
My previous backup before Android Studio 2.0 does not have that folder.

Inside the folder, there's a file called mockable-android-23.jar with around 22mb size.

Is this auto generated now? How to auto delete it when cleaning up project?

Comment: You shouldn't bother backing up the build folder since everything in there is automatically generated. You should look into using git + .gitignore instead of manually backing up, much safer.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue after upgraded to Android Studio 2.x. Don't have such issue under 1.5.x (Build -> Clean project) done automatically nicely for me.